# Image, Kernels and invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

[image]

I have question about d and e. I find the $Im(T)=\begin{bmatrix} a-b\\c-d \end{bmatrix}$, but I do not know how to write the basis of it.

And I think about (e) it should in  form of $\begin{bmatrix} a-b\\b-a \end{bmatrix}$. This is has only one basis $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$ Thus is not invertible. It this right?
Thanks

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text as they are not searchable.  Take the time to typeset them (in *MathJax*, of course), as it shows consideration for those who might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job! For (d): we have $T\begin{pmatrix}x & 0 \\ y& 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbf{F}^2$, so $T$ is surjective. Hence a basis for $\operatorname{Im}T$ is simply a basis for $\mathbf{F}_2$, for example the canonical basis $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Your solution to (e) is correct. The image of $T|_U$ is one-dimensional, hence $T|_U:U\to \mathbf{F}^2$ is not invertible.